# Glassfish 5: specify document base to store the uploaded files on Server's file system

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, file-upload, glassfish

I am building a JSF2.2 web application and server is GlassFish V5. I am looking to configure the directly where I could store the files uploaded my the users of the website.

I am using the following code to store the files in the server's (Mac) path of `/var/gdf` (`gdf` being the web app's context name).

The code that fails is `part.write("/var/gdf/"+getFileName(part));` where `part` is an instance of `javax.servlet.http.Part;` And the code for `getFileName(part)` is as follows:-

```java
private static String getFileName(Part part){
     String filename=null;
     for (String cd : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
          if (cd.trim().startsWith("filename")){
               filename=cd.substring(cd.indexOf('=')+1).trim();
          }
     }
     return filename;
}
```

However, with each reboot of the Glassfish server, I see the following error on the logs:

> Severe:   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /Users///glassfish5/glassfish/domains/domain1/generated/jsp/gdf/var/gdf/2O4A1012.JPG
>   (No such file or directory)

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add in the code you're using! Could you edit your post and add that in please?

Comment: Code that fails is part.write("/var/gdf/"+getFileName(part)); where part is an instance of javax.servlet.http.Part; And the code for getFileName(part) is a follows:-private static String getFileName(Part part){
        String filename=null;
        for (String cd : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
            if (cd.trim().startsWith("filename")){
                filename=cd.substring(cd.indexOf('=')+1).trim();
            }
            
        }
        return filename;
    }

Comment: @Mike pl see my comments above.